# Redux: user action vs logic action

Tags: redux, react-redux

Let's say I have a list and a button. An element of this list can be selected (only one at a time). If an element is selected, the button will do changes `A`, if not, it will do changes `B`.

My question is, should I have the button fire `ACTION_BUTTON_CLICKED` and the reducer can figure out if it's supposed to do `A` or `B` based on it's current state (`isElementSelected`) or should the button decide which action to fire, `ACTION_A` or `ACTION_B`?

Obs.: they button will have it's text as `Button(A)` or `Button(B)` based on whether an element is selected or not.

Comment: Have the action creator figure it out, you want to do all your logic and heavy lifting here, and have the reducers be as pure as possible.

Comment: so the action creator access the state in the store? and the reducer would be pure in both cases, since it would be accessing the current state.

Comment: also, what would the action creator be? `ActionCreatorForButtonClick` ?

Comment: No, just pass the action creator whatever it needs to run the logic, then pass the result to the reducers. You do not have access to the store in the action creators, they are functional so you just work with whatever you pass to them . Name it whatever suits you best.

Comment: So when the button is clicked (in the component), I access the store, get the state `isElementSelected` and pass that value to the action creator? still, should I have one action `ACTION_BUTTON_CLICKED` or 2 actions `ACTION_A` and `ACTION_B` that the action creator can return?

Comment: You don't access the store at any point except connecting it to the container mapstatetoprops. Your component should have all the props it needs to run, so you pass whatever props that action needs. You can have 2 separate actions or just architect your state to be smarter so you only need one. With redux you should take a little bit of time to architect your state tree so you can cleanly and elegantly do things like your scenario here. Give it a shot and if you have trouble paste the code in the question.